# How to change CSS style of div after onclick method

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
.step_box {
    border: 1.0px solid rgb(204, 204, 204);
    border-radius: 10.0px 10.0px 10.0px 10.0px;
}
.step_box:hover{
background: rgb(184, 225, 252);
}
.selected {
    background-color : #fff000;
}
</style>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('.step_wrapper').on('click','.step_box',function () {
         $('.step_box').removeClass('selected');
         $(this).addClass('selected')
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="step_wrapper">
<div class="step_box" onclick="show('Page1');"> <span>Content of page 1</span></div>
<div class="step_box" onclick="show('Page2');"> <span>Content of page 2</span></div>
<div class="step_box" onclick="show('Page3');"> <span>Content of page 3</span></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Right now I have 3 child divs inside one parent div. Right now the step_box divs show a background color when hovering. However; after the onclick method, I want the stepbox div to keep the background color with the style of ".selected". That way it highlights the div the user clicked on.

Any advice?

It works [on this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HABdx/1/) but not when i load it on my browser, am i linking the jquery to html correctly?

I'm open to suggestions if there are any other suggestions on how to do this, thanks!

Comment: Add the css on the page load function? Like he click on the div to show the content, not web page load

Comment: I would like a function like the one shown here: http://jsfiddle.net/gSAjV/2/

Comment: The page loads up and the divs have no background color, but then would like to add a background color after the div is clicked to highlight the option the user clicked on

Comment: Your fiddle works for me

Comment: @Oriol, you are able to change the background color to the fixed color provided in the script after clicking the option?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is my revision:  I added .ready() function to your code..

```
<html>
    <head>
    <style type="text/css">
    .step_box {
        border: 1.0px solid rgb(204, 204, 204);
        border-radius: 10.0px 10.0px 10.0px 10.0px;
    }
    .step_box:hover, #selected_step_box, .QuickStartLong:hover {
        background: rgb(184, 225, 252);
    }
    .selected {
        background-color : #fff000;
    }
    </style>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $( document ).ready( function(){
        $('.step_wrapper').on('click','.step_box',function () {
             $('.step_box').removeClass('selected');
             $(this).addClass('selected')
        });
    });
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="step_wrapper">
    <div class="step_box" > <span>Content of page 1</span></div>
    <div class="step_box" > <span>Content of page 2</span></div>
    <div class="step_box" > <span>Content of page 3</span></div>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Try this approach - [**version 2**](http://jsfiddle.net/HABdx/3/)

**css**

```
.selected {
    background-color : #fff000;
}
```

**js**

```
$('.step_wrapper').on('click','.step_box',function () {
    $('.step_box').removeClass('selected');
    $(this).addClass('selected')
});
```

Try this [**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/HABdx/1/) :

```
.step_box:hover, #selected_step_box, .QuickStartLong:hover {
    background-color: rgb(184, 225, 252) !important;
}
```

as you can see..just add **!important** in your css..to prevent your style in hover background-color to be ignored..

Comment: I added it but it still only shows the hovering background color and not the fixed background color when I click on a certain div

Comment: it works on the demo you provided but not when I load it onto my browser, I updated the code above with the comments provided, anything you see that is off?

Comment: according to the firebug this is your error -- **ReferenceError: show is not defined** the `onclick="show('Page1');"` makes your script not working..

Comment: please see edit..and if you want to back your `onclick="show('Page3');"` please provide corresponding function() for `show(var string)`... :D

Comment: Nice! that .ready() function did the trick. I also was able to add back the script that i had originally for switching pages, now i am able to highlight the div that corresponds to the page selected. thanks!

Comment: Thanks. How to add a reset div in this case. Like onclick reset to original color.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
$('.step_wrapper').on('click','.step_box',function () {
    $(this).parent().find('.step_box').css('background-color', '');
    $(this).css('background-color', '#fff000');
});
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/HABdx/2/)

Note: this is only an improvement of the other answer, because I don't understand your problem very well.

Comment: It works well in the demo, and I notice i need jquery for this function to work, is there a method to this without having to download jquery?

Answer (score 1):

For this kind of things, AngularJS comes in very handy.

Just add an `ng-class` to your div element, e.g. selected, and then associate that class to a behaviour on your css. I would do something like:

```
<html ng-app="ExampleApp">
<head>
    <script src="scripts/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        (function() {
            var app = angular.module('ExampleApp', []);
            app.controller('ExampleController', function(){
                this.selected = 0; // or 1 if you want the first to be selected by default
                this.isSelected = function(value){
                    return this.selected === value;
                };
                this.setSelected = function(value){
                    this.selected=value;
                };
            });
        })();
    </script>
    <style type="text/css">
        .selected {
            color: #000;
        } 
    <style>
</head>
<body>
    <div ng-controller="ExampleController as examplectrl">
        <div ng-click="examplectrl.setSelected(1)" ng-class="{selected: examplectrl.isSelected(1)}" >
        <!-- Your content -->
        </div>
        <div ng-click="examplectrl.setSelected(2)" ng-class="{selected: examplectrl.isSelected(2)}" >
        <!-- Your content -->
        </div>
        <div ng-click="examplectrl.setSelected(3)" ng-class="{selected: examplectrl.isSelected(3)}" >
        <!-- Your content -->
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

You need to have the angular.min.js file in your files. I didn't use your classes in particular because I figured that doing it this way would help the community a little more.